# Is there a way to know why my react app is showing blank on a subdomain in cpanel

Tags: reactjs, subdomain, cpanel

Basically my reactjs project will not show a blank page on a subdomain but will show on the main domain

I tried to place my build on the public_html file and it shows the project but when i place it on the subdomains file it just displays a blank page

Comment: Your subdomains' DNS should be set on your IP, can you ping your subdomain or telnet?

Comment: Yeah ok, If you want people to help i guess you should tell us more details. What have you tried so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: @Palencar I tried placing it on the public_html and yes it works but when i have a folder inside public_html and place my build there and go to e.g. https://example.com/folder it displays blank

Comment: and also when i inspect element it reads the index.html but thats it

Comment: did you try to follow this tuto ? https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6

Comment: yes I did and it works on the main domain i.e in the public_html folder.. but when I place it inside a folder i.e public_html/folder and then use the folder as root in my subdomain and then when i go to the subdomain link it just displays a blank page

Comment: In your project which router are you using?

Comment: react router is what i used

Comment: i meant which type of router in react router, like BrowserRouter, Hashrouter .... try looking through this post https://muffinman.io/react-router-subfolder-on-server/ you might find something interesting.